# Find socket ref by socket id in socketioxide rust Socket IO

Tags: rust, socket.io

Is there a method like java implementation's getClient in Rust?

```
/**
 * Get client by uuid from default namespace
 *
 * @param uuid - id of client
 * @return client
 */
public SocketIOClient getClient(UUID uuid) {
    return namespacesHub.get(Namespace.DEFAULT_NAME).getClient(uuid);
}
```

find alias function in rust

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is now possible with v0.9.1:
https://docs.rs/socketioxide/latest/socketioxide/struct.SocketIo.html#method.get_socket

Comment: Links can die, could you please copy the relevant code snippet that answers the question in the answer?